# Faulty inetres.adml on Windows 7 client?

Tags: windows-7

I am a system integrator in training and I've been running into an issue when setting up our systems.
After installing all updates on Windows 7 there is an error message when opening the Group Policy Editor, something along the lines of "The in the attribute "$string.VerMgmtAuditModeEnable") requested resource displayName could not be found - File: C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\inetres.admx"

This error doesn't necessarily affect the normal operations the systems are intended for, it is annoying nonetheless. 
I have already determined that this is due to a faulty .adml file for at least the German package. Currently my workaround is to copy over a working .adml file from one of our workstations that are unaffected somehow; this, however, is quite a hassle because it requires a lot of clicking with taking over file ownership and all.

I can only assume that one of the Windows updates is responsible, but I haven't been able to isolate a specific update as of yet.

I was wondering if anyone has encountered this issue before and can offer some insight into how this comes to be, or whether there is an easier way to fix it than my workaround - my google searches only turned up a few results involving Windows server operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly sounds like somebody updated the Administrative Template without updating the corresponding language file.

Go to Microsoft's [Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40905) and download the latest release of the Administrative Templates for Internet Explorer.

You did not speficy what language you're seeing this with, but I can confirm that at least the `en-US` version of the latest release (August 2014) contains a string with identifier `VerMgmtAuditModeEnable`

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is KB3093983 Cumulative Security Update for Internet Explorer versions 7, 8, 9, 10 and 11, released on October 12, 2015.

The problem affects all Windows versions, which are using a language setting different than en-US, as soon as KB3093983 is installed.

The problem is that KB3093983 installs an updated inetres.admx file and only includes and installs the corresponding en-US inetres.adml updated language file. Leaving inetres.admx and inetres.adml mismatched for any other language.

Answer (score 0):

inetres.admx was updated for Internet Explorer 11 (presumably for every other previous version of IE as well).  What version of IE is running on the Windows 7 workstation?

The top few lines of the ADMX XML document specify the **minRequiredRevision="11.0"**  I suggest you check and see if your language file matches the ADMX in this regard.

If you have deployed an update to Internet Explorer updates as part of your integration work, did you use the IEAK and did you specify any particular locales?